# Create Drop-down menu in shopping Cart Page

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

In given link , http://liferaybangalore.com/index.php add one product to cart and go to VIEW CART ,

Above PROCEED TO CHECKOUT Button i want to add custome code for drop-down menus like(Children Education, Womens Support etc...).

`/app/design/frontend/em0122/default/template/checkout/cart/totals.phtml`

At end to this total.phtml page am writing code, While selecting dropdown menu should attach in mail with other details.
Please refer the attached screen shot.

Please help me out.[image]

Comment: What do you want to display in the dropdown? Dynamic values, static values? Do these values depend on our values, i.e. conditional logic?

Comment: Static Values in dropdown, like ( Girls Education , Boys Education , Womens Support, Donation etc... ) these are the static menus in drop-down,

Comment: and selected menu should attach in orders mail with  other details, please how to do , help me out.

Comment: Can reply anyone ,, suggest me some idea about above given question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attributes to save extra data for orders. Have a look at the "Saving extra data with an order in Magento" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370235/saving-extra-data-with-an-order-in-magento).

It's best to write a simple custom extension to add your attribute(s) and then you need to listen to the correct event to write that extra piece of data to the database (e.g. sales_convert_quote_to_order). clockworkgeek has posted a nice overview for a possible solution.

Comment: can you please explain specific..?